# Баг предметов при столковении. произвольное направления unity (2d)

Tags: unity3d

При подборе предмета. с включенным кинетиком на нем. и слоем который не взаимодействует ни с одним из слоев. при наведении его на обьект начинает получать ускорение. подскажите в чем может быть проблема.
ссылка на видео
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/9feWRpzhzAFWeA

```
    [SerializeField] float Force;
    public Transform grabDetect;
    public Transform boxholder;
    public float rayDist;
    public bool HoldItem;

    private GameObject _grabbedObject;


    public void Hold()
    {
        RaycastHit2D grabCheck = Physics2D.Raycast(grabDetect.position, Vector2.right * transform.localScale, rayDist);


        if (!HoldItem)
        {


            if (grabCheck.collider != null && grabCheck.collider.tag == "HoldAndThrow")

            {

                _grabbedObject = grabCheck.collider.gameObject;

                _grabbedObject.gameObject.layer = 14;
                _grabbedObject.transform.parent = boxholder;
                _grabbedObject.transform.position = boxholder.position;
                               
          
                _grabbedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
             
                
                if (grabCheck.collider != null)
                {
                    HoldItem = true;
                }

            }


        }
        else
        {


            grabCheck.collider.gameObject.layer = 13;
            grabCheck.collider.gameObject.transform.parent = null;

            grabCheck.collider.gameObject.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;

            grabCheck.collider.gameObject.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, 0.3f) * Force;


            HoldItem = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

нужно добавить контроль велосити в 0  и тогда ни чего бегать не будет